# Need help creating function to convert celsius to fahrenheit when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html

The code below is what I have for now. Excuse me for the way this code is. The professor wants it this way. Basically everything I have is working, except converting the input in the **celsius** box to display the conversion in the **fahrenheit** box, when the button is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>Celsius to Fahrenheit Converter</title>
    <script>
    function degree() {
        document.getElementById("h2").style.color = "red";
        var x;
        if () {
            x = document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
            document.getElementById("f").value = Math.round(x);
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form NAME="test">
    <h2 id="h2">Celsius to Fahrenheit Converter</h2>
    <P>Enter temp in celsius: <INPUT id="c" TYPE="text" NAME="celsius"><BR><BR>
    <P>Temp in fahrenheit: <INPUT id="f" TYPE="text" NAME="fahrenheit"><BR><BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="Button" Value="Convert" onClick="degree()">
    </P>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("h2").style.color = "blue";
    </script>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: And what issue are you having?

Comment: Why the `if () {`?

Comment: You have an empty `if` condition, which I suspect is a syntax error (and is probably being reported in your browser's debugging console).  What *should* you be checking in that condition?

Comment: i left the if empty as what i had before wasn't working

Comment: well leaving it empty won't work either

Comment: I'm not sure what i should declare the if statement as in this scenario, i'm fairly new to coding

Comment: @SeanBruce: Well, you'd start by defining the logic you want to implement.  What is that logic?  What code do you use to attempt to implement it?  In what way does that code not work as intended?

Comment: Is there some condition that needs to be checked? If not, remove the whole `if`. (Don't forget to remove the matching closing bracket  (`}`))

Comment: Any recommendation on what i could set the if () to here

Comment: tell us in words what the condition would be....and go from there

Comment: Okay that helps, i got it. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getting the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) at Line 8

When looking into your browsers console, you can fix this issue by simply removing the if with empty conditions!

```
function degree() {
    document.getElementById("h2").style.color = "red";
    var x;
    if () {
        x = document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
        document.getElementById("f").value = Math.round(x);
    }
}
```

will look like this:

```
function degree() {
    document.getElementById("h2").style.color = "red";
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById("c").value * 9 / 5 + 32;
    document.getElementById("f").value = Math.round(x);
}
```